# Why PostgreSQL is not working in python?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

```
root@user:~# pip install psycopg2
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): psycopg2 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

Why PostgreSQL  is not working in python?

```
root@user:~$ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Oct 20 2014, 15:05:29) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import postgresql
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named postgresql
```

Comment: Because you do not read documentation? http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html

Comment: Why are you trying to import `postgresql`? The project you installed is called `psycopg2`. Is there documentation or a tutorial somwhere that gave you the impression the module to import was called `postgresql`?

Answer (score 5):

The module is called `psycopg2`, import it instead of `postgresql`:

```
import psycopg2
```

Demo:

```
>>> import psycopg2
>>> psycopg2.__version__
'2.5.4 (dt dec pq3 ext)'
```

---

There is though the PostgreSQL pure-python python3-specific driver called [`py-postgresql`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-postgresql). You are probably mixing with/referring to it:

```
$ python3
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr  3 2014, 20:36:56) 
>>> import postgresql
>>> postgresql.version
'1.1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should import `psycopg2` instead of `postgresql`.